# What does this binary search count python function do

Tags: python, tree, binary

Hi I would just like a quick explanation of what this function does and how it works. My teacher could not explain it in a way I understood. It is part of a binary search tree program and from what I could gather this function counts the number of times a specific number (d) occurs in the tree.

```
def count(self, d):    
    pos = self.root
    while pos != None:
        if d == pos.data:
            return pos.mult
        if d < pos.data:
            pos = pos.left
        else:
            pos = pos.right
    return 0
```

Comment: This is very much self explanatory!!

Comment: Sorry, i meant the conditions in the while statement

Comment: The loop will transverse from root node to last leaf node!! So while loop will run till it reaches the last leaf node which will be `None` and hence the `while` loop will terminate as the condition will then become `False`

Answer (score 0):

The function does not count how many times a specific number occurs in the tree.

It merely searches for the number. If the number is found it returns `pos.mult`.

If the number is smaller or equal to d, it goes to the right child of the node that it is currently at. If it is bigger it goes to the left child.

This is done until it reaches the leafs (while loop). The leafs will have "None" as right/left child. It then stops the tree traverse and returns 0.

Comment: I suspect it's called `count` because multiple instances of a value are created by incrementing the `mult` property.

Comment: It the number if less than the current node it goes to the left child not the right child